# How to echo tag description on loop-page.php using WPeC 3.8

Tags: tags

I'm trying to display the 'Tag Description' on my tagged pages. I've added an if statement to loop-page.php already to only show custom text when a tagged page is being displayed...

```
<?php } elseif ( is_tax ( 'product_tag' ) ){ ?><h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?> print out this text on page</h1>
```

... but I don't know the code to output the tag description.

Does anyone know the code to display the tag description? I want it to go after the H1 in the above code. I'm trying to output the description that is entered when you go into Wordpress Admin>Products>Product Tags>Description using WPeC 3.8.

I'm using the Twenty10 theme, WPec 3.8 and WP 3.1

Thanks for your help

ChainsawDR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the term by its slug and echo out the descriptions

```
elseif {is_tax ( 'product_tag' ) ){ 
  $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
  $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
  $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
  ?><h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $current_term->description; ?></h1> <?php
}
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so very much!

I haven't yet gotten to the stage of developing my product category pages yet, but I think if I also need to pull in the description for these pages that I'll be able to adapt this code also.

Thanks again, really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't know how to mark this as [Solved] and don't yet have the reputation to Vote Up your answer, I'll come back to do this once I have that ability.
Thanks again